# How to open Gallery app directly to pick images

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the following code to open the Gallery app directly to pick images from the gallery. But it provides another option as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

So is it possible to open the Gallery app directly without showing any options? The code I used is shown below.

```
Intent imageintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
imageintent.setType("image/*");             
imageintent.putExtra("crop", "true");
imageintent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
imageintent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
imageintent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(imageintent, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: I used this and in result it add another two more option google drive & dropbox.

Comment: you should create your own file selection system of file explorer. :)

Comment: @ChintanRathod Any example or sample code for that.

Comment: Have you checked my edited answer?

Answer (score 3):

***Here is the solution.***

**Layout.xml**

```
 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/d109dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/d109dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/man"
                    app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/d2dp" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 case R.id.imageButtonEdit:
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                    "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(EditProfileActivity.this);

                    if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                        if (result)
                            cameraIntent();

                    } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                        if (result)
                            galleryIntent();

                    } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();

   private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}


private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getApplicationContext(), data);
        // final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }

        editLocation.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}{1}{2}", String.valueOf(address), getString(R.string.textComma), Html.fromHtml(attributions)));


    }
}

 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

**Set Uses Permission in Manifest.xml file**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I am using your code, chooser is not coming that is fine, but after opening native gallery in Oreo OS native gallery gridview the image thumbnails are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: It add another two more option google drive & dropbox. I want to open the gallery directly.

Answer (score 0):

When the intent to open an another app is fired, the android will show up the applications that can handle this intent. It is not something that can be fixed from the application code. The solution is to set the application as default for that perticular action.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your question is Custom Grid View selection.

I found a good sample which will allow you to display all images from your gallery to your activity. This is different. Because this will not open other application. You can do customization on this code.

Name of sample is **[AndroidGridViewCompatLib](https://github.com/paramvir-b/AndroidGridViewCompatLib)**

To implement this code, you need to write following code in your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Done" />

    <com.rokoder.android.lib.support.v4.widget.GridViewCompat
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/doneButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </com.rokoder.android.lib.support.v4.widget.GridViewCompat>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following code will be in your activity file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance) {
    ...
    ...
    gridView = (GridViewCompat) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here example is `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, you can also set it `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    button_pick_image.setOnClickListener(view -> start());
        final Activity activity = Main2Activity.this;
        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, RC_CAMERA);
        } else {
            captureImage();
        }
    }




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == RC_CAMERA) {
        if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            captureImage();
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

private void captureImage() {
    ImagePicker.cameraOnly().start(Main2Activity.this,RC_IMAGE_PICKER);
}

Action1<List<com.esafirm.imagepicker.model.Image>> action = this::printImages;

private rx.Observable<List<com.esafirm.imagepicker.model.Image>> getImagePickerObservable() {
    return RxImagePicker.getInstance()
            .start(this, ImagePicker.create(this));
}
public void start() {

    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker.create(this)
            .toolbarArrowColor(Color.RED) // set toolbar arrow up color
            .toolbarFolderTitle("Folder") // folder selection title
            .toolbarImageTitle("Tap to select"); // image selection title

    imagePicker.multi(); // multi mode (default mode)
    imagePicker.limit(10) // max images can be selected (99 by default)
            .showCamera(true) // show camera or not (true by default)
            .imageDirectory("Camera")   // captured image directory name ("Camera" folder by default)
            .imageFullDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()) // can be full path
            .start(); // start image picker activity with request code
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        images = (ArrayList<com.esafirm.imagepicker.model.Image>) ImagePicker.getImages(data);
        printImages(images);
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void printImages(List<com.esafirm.imagepicker.model.Image> images) {
    if (images == null) return;

    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).getPath()).append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
}
```

}

//use this or refer this https://jitpack.io/#esafirm/android-image-picker